# About inheritance in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, inheritance

I have a WCF constructor like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    methodA.....

    [OperationContract]
    methodB....

    [OperationContract]
    methodC....
}
```

and I also have a class which inherited the above interface like this

```
public class A: IService
    {
        methodA(){}
        methodB(){}
        methodC(){}
    }
```

there is a iphone application which calls the class A for comunication with server,and 
there will be another new iphone application which will call a class B for comunication with server.

so now I must create the class B which is almost the same as class A .
but in class B ,there will only be some modifies in methodB and there's no need to have methodC,

I was asked to reuse the class A and to think about of using **inherance** instead of writing repeated codes.

I have no idea how to use the inherance to do this work. can anyone help me? thank you!

Comment: Mark `MethodB` virtual in class `A` and `override` it in class `B`.. you can't remove a method but you can throw an exception if it's used (for `MethodC`)

Answer (score 0):

Your exact requirements are unclear. You did not explain what you can and can't change. You need to add additional constraints if you want a more specific answer. I will show the preferred approach.

Using this inheritance structure:

```
public class ServiceBase
{
    public Foo MethodA()
    {
        // Shared implementation
    }

    public abstract Foo MethodB();
}

public class ServiceA : ServiceBase
{
    public override Foo MethodB()
    {
        // ServiceA-specific implementation
    }

    public Foo MethodC()
    {
        // Only in ServiceA
    }
}

public class ServiceB : ServiceBase
{
    public override Foo MethodB()
    {
        // ServiceA-specific implementation
    }
}
```

This way both services inherit the implementation of `MethodA()`, while either service has its own implementation of `MethodB()`. `MethodC()` is only required and thus only present in `ServiceA`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use 2 separate service classes, you'll have to have 2 separate WCF services. Use a second **interface**, instead of a second class. Then you can have **2 endpoints** on a single service, serving two different applications:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    methodA.....

    [OperationContract]
    methodB....

    [OperationContract]
    methodC....
}

[ServiceContract]   // this is for the second app
public interface IService2
{
    [OperationContract]
    methodA.....

    [OperationContract]
    methodB2....   // a different method
}


public class A: IService, IService2
{
    methodA(){}   // used by app 1 and app 2
    methodB(){}   // used by app 1
    methodB2(){}  // used by app 2
    methodC(){}   // used by app 1
}
```